# MVC3 uploadify uploading images to folders

Tags: image, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, uploadify

I am using uploadify for uploading multiple images with progress in ASP.NET MVC3 and I want to upload lets say from url Gallery/Upload/2 to folder with name 2 and Gallery/Upload/3 to folder 3 and so on. I just don´t know how. For get working uploading I used this [sample](http://midnightprogrammer.net/post/Upload-Files-In-RAZOR-With-jQuery-Uploadify-Plugin.aspx) and modified sample upload script to this:

```
public string Upload(HttpPostedFileBase fileData)
        {
            var id = 2;
            var fotka = new Photo();
            fotka.GalleryId = id;
            fotka.Description = fileData.FileName;
            fotka.Name = fileData.FileName;
            db.Photos.Add(fotka);
            db.SaveChanges();
            var fileNameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileData.FileName);
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileData.FileName);
            string path = Server.MapPath("~/Fotky/") + id.ToString() + "\\" + fileNameWithoutExtension;
            // var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Fotky/"), galleryId.ToString(), "/", fileNameWithoutExtension);
            using (var input = new Bitmap(fileData.InputStream))
            {
                int width;
                int height;
                if (input.Width > input.Height)
                {
                    width = 128;
                    height = 128 * input.Height / input.Width;
                }
                else
                {
                    height = 128;
                    width = 128 * input.Width / input.Height;
                }
                using (var thumb = new Bitmap(width, height))
                using (var graphic = Graphics.FromImage(thumb))
                {
                    graphic.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                    graphic.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                    graphic.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

                    graphic.DrawImage(input, 0, 0, width, height);
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/Fotky/") + id.ToString());
                    using (var output = System.IO.File.Create(path + "_small" + Path.GetExtension(fileName)))
                    {
                        thumb.Save(output, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    }
                }
            }
            fileData.SaveAs(path + Path.GetExtension(fileName));

            return "ok";
        }
```

as you can see I am using id as 2 as default, but I want to get it from parameters, is it posible? And how? Thank you

No one knows answer? It´s really important for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have your controller action take the id as action argument:

```
public string Upload(HttpPostedFileBase fileData, string id)
{
    ...
}
```

and then pass this id when configuring your plugin:

```
$("#fileuploader").fileUpload({
    'uploader': '@Url.Content("~/Scripts/uploader.swf")',
    'cancelImg': '@Url.Content("~/Images/cancel.png")',
    'buttonText': 'Select Image',
    'script': '@Url.Action("Upload", "Home", new { id = "2" })',
    'folder': '@Url.Content("~/uploads")',
    'fileDesc': 'Image Files',
    'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png',
    'multi': true,
    'auto': true
});
```

Comment: Thanks. That is a great solution. I have been messing around for quite a while in the past. Now I can use Uploadify to its full strength. Thank you!